# Nested query not working in Java Spring + Postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

Spring Boot v2.5.5 + Postgresql 10

Nested query on Java Spring Boot Service:

```
String query = "select d.*
                from (
                  ( select a.*
                    from table1 a )            --subquery1
                EXCEPT
                  ( select c.*                 --subquery2                
                    from table2 b, table1 c
                    where b.table1_id = c.id AND b.h_id = 1 
                        AND b.h_id = c.h_id 
                        AND ( tstzrange(  b.start_date , b.end_date , 
                              '[]')  
                        && tstzrange('2023-04-16 10:42:00.0','2023-04- 
                           16 14:42:00.0', '[]' )) 
                  ) 
                ) d"


List<D> dlist = new ArrayList<>();
dlist = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, D.class).getResultList();
```

subquery1 returns 6 record, subquery2 return 1 records.
EXCEPT in this nested query works fine in PGAdmin and returns 5 records, but in Spring Boot EXCEPT not work and I get all 6 records from subquery1

Is this a problem in the Hibernate?

Comment: Is this the actual query formatting in the code?

Comment: Popular option 1 - you are connected to a different database. Popular option 2 - a session  with  long running transaction produces different result as other session. Simple activate sql trace and replay the result query in the correct DB. Generally has Hibernate varying scoring, but *"Is shit a problem in Hibernate?"* is may be too hard;)

Comment: I'm using only one DB connection.  
 In application.properties setting next parameters:
 
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.session.jdbc.schema=public
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout=120
spring.session.jdbc.initializer.enabled=true

and in SPRING_SESSION table only 1 active session.

I don't use org.hibernate.SessionFactory for seseion managament - i need to use SessionFactory ?

Comment: I found that subquery2 down not work in Spring Boot !! subquery2 returns 0 records, but in PGADmin return 1 record ! Why ?

Comment: Select * from table1 b where tstzrange(b.start_date , b.end_date , ‘[]’) && tstzrange(‘2023-04-16 09:17:00.0′,’2023-04-16 11:17:00.0’, ‘[]’ ) dont work in Spring.
All date overlapping functions such as OVERLAP and daterange from application dont work too. In PgAdmin all date overlapping functions works, but don t work in Spring